# CSS height issues in IE8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-8

I'm running a little main navigation test at http://tools.weddingideasmag.com/MainNavTest/

The trouble is, I can't get the drop menu height to work right in IE8.

This is what the page looks like on Chrome and is displaying fine…

[image]

here's the IE8 version…

[image]

Can anyone help please, it's almost sorted but I can't figure out this bug

Comment: Can you post us some code?

Comment: Hi Mat - are you not able to see the code via the source? Is it not easier to do that than paste lots of code and css?

Comment: The easiest would be to narrow down the code to a small sample that reproduces the problem and post it here. If the question just asks about code on your site, how useful will it be to someone else in a year's time, when your site's code is completely different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi Have gone through your css

found out that in you flatnavie.css

you have

```
.single-height {
/*height: 230px;*/
}

.double-height {
/*height: 400px;*/
}
```

## Just uncomment that & it is working

## UPDATED

OK, use this

```
.single-height {
height: 200px;
max-height: 800px;
}
```

Comment: Hi Vikas, I've done that because I don't want to have to specify a fixed height. If I do that, all submenus have the same height, but all of them have different length content in them.

Answer (score 1):

Welcome to Internet Explorer. Enjoy your road!

I got the same problem, and I resolved it because my doctype wasn't valid.

If you got a bad doctype, IE will go on a different mode than expected.

Just put `<!DOCTYPE html>` and it will be fine and add `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />` on the `<head>`.

Hope this can be a little bit helpful.

Comment: Hum... I just checked on IE8 and it's working great for me... There is just the display of li that is not rly good in some case. Are you sure you're not in IE7 ?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is actually coming from the JavaScript in `flatnav.js`. There's some code in that file that is intended to make all columns in a submenu the same height:

```
$(window).load(function(){
  $('.flat-nav>ul>li').mouseover(function() {           
    var x = 0;

    $(this).children('ul.column-based').children('li').each(function() {
      if(this.offsetHeight > x) {
        x = this.offsetHeight;
      }
    });

    $(this).children('ul.column-based').children('li').each(function() {
      $(this).css("height", x + "px");
    });

   // more code...

  });
});
```

It seems that `x` is being calculated too early in IE8, resulting in a very small height for the menus.

While there might be fixes for that JS. I'd prefer to do the 'equal column heights' in CSS since it works well in your case. Try commenting out/removing the JS above, then add the following to the bottom of `flatnav.css`:

```
div.flat-nav ul.column-based > li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  float: none;
  width: 145px;
}
```

Try it here: http://jsbin.com/OJiGiQoF/2